# Unexpected behaviour of knockout computed and subscribe

Tags: knockout.js

I have following data structure

```
[{
    "name": "root1",
    "ecomCategories": [{
      "name": "sub11"
    }, {
      "name": "sub12",
      "ecomCategories": null
    }, {
      "name": "sub13",
      "ecomCategories": null
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "root2",
    "ecomCategories": [{
      "name": "sub21",
      "ecomCategories": null
    }]
  }]
```

Now i want to show drop downs which will change on selecting of root category:
please see this fiddle -- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devrahul/y7497cbL/1/)

**However if i am updating any observable in the subscribed function then its changes are reflected in the parent observable**

Steps to reproduce this issue in fiddle:

1. Select root category "root1" it will have 3 sub categories sub11, sub12, sub13
2. Select any subcategory i.e. sub11
3. select root category "root2"
4. Again select root category "root1"
   **Now you will see only one sub category in the Sub category drop down where as it should have 3 sub categories**

```js
// Here's my data model
var ViewModel = function() {
  this.rootCategory = ko.observableArray([{
    "name": "root1",
    "ecomCategories": [{
      "name": "sub11"
    }, {
      "name": "sub12",
      "ecomCategories": null
    }, {
      "name": "sub13",
      "ecomCategories": null
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "root2",
    "ecomCategories": [{
      "name": "sub21",
      "ecomCategories": null
    }]
  }]);
  this.newObjectToSave = ko.observable();
  this.selectedCategory = ko.observable();
  this.selectedSubCategory = ko.observable();

  var that = this;
  //subscribers  
  this.selectedCategory.extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });
  this.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(newVal) {

    if (newVal != undefined) {
      that.newObjectToSave(newVal);
      // newObjectToSave().ecomCategories = [];
    }

  });

  this.selectedSubCategory.extend({
    notify: 'always'
  });
  this.selectedSubCategory.subscribe(function(subCat) {

    if (subCat != undefined) {
      that.newObjectToSave().ecomCategories = [subCat];
      that.newObjectToSave(that.newObjectToSave().ecomCategories[0]);
    }

  });





  //computed 
  this.subCategories = ko.computed(function() {
    if (this.selectedCategory() != undefined) {
      return this.selectedCategory().ecomCategories;
    } else {
      return "";
    }

  }, this);





};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); // This makes Knockout get to work
```

```css
.paddingTop15 {
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.browseCategory select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /*Removes default chrome and safari style*/
  -moz-appearance: none;
  /* Removes Default Firefox style*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row paddingTop15">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Select Root Category:
      <br>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm browseCategory">
        <select class="btn btn-default" data-bind="options: rootCategory,
                        optionsText: 'name',
                        value: selectedCategory,
                        optionsCaption: 'Select Category'"></select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row paddingTop15">

    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Select SubCategory:
      <br>
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm browseCategory">
        <select class="btn btn-default" data-bind="options: subCategories,
                        optionsText: 'name',
                        value: selectedSubCategory,
                        optionsCaption: 'Select Sub Category'"></select>
      </div>
    </div>



  </div>
</div>
```

So why updating of "newObjectToSave" is updating "selectedCategory" value ???

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing is happening because you are passing `newVal` by reference to `newObjectToSave`. At that time the value in `newObjectToSave` observable links to one of the selected elements in `rootCategory`

```
this.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(newVal) {

    if (newVal != undefined) {
      that.newObjectToSave(newVal);
      // newObjectToSave().ecomCategories = [];
    }

});
```

...and then you modify ecomCategories on the referenced value, causing the options to modify:

```
this.selectedSubCategory.subscribe(function(subCat) {

    if (subCat != undefined) {
      that.newObjectToSave().ecomCategories = [subCat];
      that.newObjectToSave(that.newObjectToSave().ecomCategories[0]);
    }

});
```

**Solution**: I would suggest to deep copy the newVal object so that it is not linked to the original value if you want to modify it afterwards:

```
this.selectedCategory.subscribe(function(newVal) {

    if (newVal != undefined) {
      var newValue = jQuery.extend(true, {}, newVal);
      that.newObjectToSave(newValue);
      // newObjectToSave().ecomCategories = [];
    }

  });
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rgppt46u/1/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Bogdan :)

Comment: @Dev if you found the answer to be correct, please mark it as so by clicking on the tick mark next to the anwer. Thanks